# Is ῥύομαι cognate with rescue?

Tags: etymology, greek, proto-indo-european

I couldn't help but wonder, while reading this verse from the Lord's Prayer, whether ῥύομαι might be cognate with the English verb *rescue*.

> καὶ μὴ εἰσενέγκῃς ἡμᾶς εἰς πειρασμόν,
>   ἀλλὰ ῥῦσαι ἡμᾶς ἀπὸ τοῦ πονηροῦ.
>
> And lead us not into temptation,
>   But rescue us from evil.
>
> [Matthew 6:13](http://www.nestle-aland.com/en/read-na28-online/text/bibeltext/lesen/stelle/50/60001/69999/)

The [entry on etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rescue&allowed_in_frame=0) did not suggest anything of the sort. It claims that *rescue* derives from the Latin verb *excutere* but stops short of making any connections to Greek.

> rescue (v.)
>   c. 1300, from stem of Old French rescorre "protect, keep safe; free, deliver" (Modern French recourre), from re-, intensive prefix (see re-), + escourre "to cast off, discharge," from Latin excutere "to shake off, drive away," from ex "out" (see ex-) + -cutere, combining form of quatere "to shake" (see quash). Related: Rescued; rescuing.

I thought there might be more to the story. Would anyone here happen to know whether ῥύομαι is cognate with *rescue*? If not, I would be equally interested in learning what PIE root or stem ῥύομαι descends from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words are unrelated: there's no way to connect *ex-cutere* with ῥύομαι. The Latin word is based on *quatio* "shake", which has a Greek cognate πάττω "sprinkle".

The etymology of ῥύομαι is a bit messy. It's part of a family of forms which include ἔρυμαι, ἐρύομαι, εἴρυτο and others (all with the same meaning). These seem to go back to a PIE root such as *ueru-, which also yields the English word *wear* and German *wehren* "defend". But there are some doubts about this because of the lack of evidence for digamma in Greek, and other etymologies have been suggested.